# PDF toolbar disabling

Tags: javascript, iframe

i have a question,

sample scenario
1. login using valid credentials
2. Click reports
3. Click view action button
actual output: pop up pdf viewer appear

Q1: how to disable the PDF toolbar and/or navigation pane ?

Q2: what if i uses iframe to then retrieve the pdf file in my system, does my iframe has a capabilities to disable the PDF toolbar and/or navigation pane ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to append this to the end of the PDF URL:

```
#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0
```

This hides the navigation and scrollbars.

The same works for embeds using iframe, just add that to the "src".

Example without toolbars: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0

Usual Example: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you're not embedding then it should work in all modern browsers, yes.